# LDAP/Java auth: How to specify workstation?

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

We have a small LAN where each user is logging into Windows via Active Directory server. I want to be able to authenticate users from Java code in the same way. I was doing this in the following way:

```
Hashtable <String, String> env = new Hashtable <>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.1:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user1");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass1"));
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
try {
    new InitialDirContext(env).close();
    return true;
} catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
    return false;
}
```

where `user1` and `pass1` was user credentals.

That worked fine until local administrator restricted access by explicitly setting a list of allowed workstations for each user. Now users are still able to log into Windows, but my code (executed on allowed workstation) produces

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - ...:
    LdapErr: ...,
    comment: AcceptSecurityContext error,
    data 531,
    ...]
```

where ["data 531" means "not permitted to logon at this workstation"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/LDAP+Error+Code+49).

So the question is: how should I authenticate a user on LDAP server when user's allowed workstations are set? Should I somehow pass current workstation to the LDAP server or what?

Comment: Maybe you really aren't allowed to login at that workstation?

Comment: I'm using the same login/password I use to log into Windows (natively, through same ActiveDirectory server), so it's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Allowed workstations parameter is set in the AD in **userWorkstations** attribute.

So you may need to set the server name that hosts your java code to the **userWorkstations** attribute in the AD for the login user.

Refere to below link for more details

[Can't get connection with AD from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766158/cant-get-connection-with-ad-from-java-code/18767613#18767613?newreg=854061f7965244399fec2b7757c3b325)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to authenticate users from Java code in the same way.

Then you want Kerberos and not LDAP bind.