# Check account locked status when authenticating with active directory using LDAP

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

I have the following Java code to authenticate to Active Directory via the LDAP method. If authentication fails, an AuthenticationException is thrown. Is it possible to determine whether the authentication failure is due to the user account being locked?

```
try {
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    new InitialDirContext(env);
    return true;
} catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
    authenticationException.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    throw exception;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766158/cant-get-connection-with-ad-from-java-code/18767613   There seem a way to get LDAP error codes that gives you information if account is locked.  I hope that helps

Comment: Note that exposing the information to the client application can be seen as a security issue since it allows to know that the user exist in the directory, and then can be a vector of attack.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. Using authenticationException.getExplanation(), I can get a string "LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 755, vece ". I can parse this string, get the error code, and determine the failure reason.