# How to pass userWorkstation through LDAP to Active Directory for login?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Similar questions on the issue.

[LDAP/Java auth: How to specify workstation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908532/ldap-java-auth-how-to-specify-workstation)

[Why do you need to include the AD server in "userWorkstations"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140697/why-do-you-need-to-include-the-ad-server-in-userworkstations)

I have a product that handles the user authentication for clients using LDAP. The client machine does not authenticate directly against Active Directory. The product server handles a login request, authenticates directly against LDAP on behalf of that user. The problem is that one customer has a user workstation whitelist turned on in Active Directory. Since, the LDAP request comes from the product server, not the client machine, it's failing the user workstation check. Below is code where I tried passing the user workstation value as a environment variables but it did not work in the customer's environment. How do I pass the property correctly for Active Directory?

Partial code fragment:

```
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);

        // Specify the Security Protocol
        if (!protocol.equals(""))
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);

        // Use whatever was passed to us
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        String userWorkstations = "test.example.com";
        env.put("userWorkstations", userWorkstations);
        env.put("User-Workstations", userWorkstations);
        log.info(String.format(
                    "Found property server.ldap.user.workstations. Adding value %s to the LDAP context.",
                    userWorkstations));
        log.info("Context dump: " + env);

        // Get a reference to a directory context
        dirContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this issue as well, but came to the conclusion that this would not make any sense.

If you were able to send the user's workstation name you would be able to authenticate on every computer.

I think your solution would be to add the name of the computer the server software runs on to the "Log On To" list of every participating user in the active directory.